# What is the meaning of the area under the curve in this case?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm doing an investigation task in math at school, in which I have to plot a diagram of Average daylight hours vs month (at least that's how I've structured it) for three different countries, derive a trigonometric model (I used a sine model for all), and calculate the area under the curve and compare them. I used this [website](https://www.worlddata.info/europe/united-kingdom/sunset.php) to get the daylight hours for Washington D.C., Kenya, and Argentina and converted it to decimals before plotting it. I initially thought the area under the curve was the average daylight per year, but it seems like I was wrong (that's what I currently think). I am really confused with the term "average daylight hours" for a month, because it is essentially the total daylight hours divided by the number of days in that month? So, I find it quite contradictory because the x-axis is supposed to be the month, but the data represents average daylight hours of a day in that month? I tried to think about the meaning of the area under the curve for that scenario, but I haven't been able to get my head around it.

Can someone please explain this confusion and the meaning of the area under the curve? Thank you!

[image: This]

This is the processed dataset I used to plot for Washington D.C.

Comment: Daylight/unit time $\times$ time = daylight, so it should mean the total amount of daylight over a time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're plotting the graph of $d(t)$ against $t$ for $t\in[0,365),$ where $d(t)$ is the average daily number of daylight hours corresponding to day $t.$

The area $\displaystyle\int_0^{365} d(t)\,\mathrm dt$ under the curve is **the total number of daylight hours in one year**, while the **average daily number of daylight hours over the year** is $\displaystyle\frac1{365}\int_0^{365} d(t)\,\mathrm dt.$

Comment: I only have data for the month, not the day. So how would I reflect that in my model? Just an idea, but would setting the equation for B as 2pi/B =365 make the model for days? And in that case, would it represent the data accurately? Thank you.

Comment: I clicked on your website and surmised that your vertical axis is derived from "Average length of day in [city]." Yes, you have month-by-month data (a discrete function),  but the fact that you wish to compute area under the curve means that you are approximating it as a continuous function; the most natural unit for $t$ then is day.

Comment: I see, then in that case, would I use this equation (2pi/B =365) to adjust my model to reflect in terms of days and not months? Edit: the B is from the equation y=Asin(B(x-C))+D

Comment: What's $B?$ Anyway, to be more careful: perhaps $\dfrac{2\pi}{|B|}=365.$ P.S. When posting on this site, do enclose mathematics between dollar signs.

Comment: So just to make sure I understood this correctly, even though I used the month-by-month data to calculate A and D, if I adjust the period of the function to 365 days to find the value of B ($2pi/B = 365), the function would be adjusted in terms of days and not months?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the suggestion! I'll upvote this answer and edit my comment as soon as I get permission. (it says I can only do it after 5 min?)

Comment: No worries! Comments are editable for only 5 minutes, though for future reference: `$\dfrac{1}{2}$`=$\dfrac12.$